# Elements separate at different zoom levels

Tags: html, css

```css
.order-page {
  margin-top: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
.order-page .order-page-left {
  width: 275px;
  background: white;
}
.order-page .order-page-right {
  width: 710px;
}
.order-page .order-page-content {
  padding: 20px 35px 45px 40px;
}
.color-box {
  background: red;
}
.orders-list .item {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  color: black;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.orders-list .item .inner {
  padding: 7px 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.orders-list .item .detail {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  width: 50px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.orders-list .item .detail .smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
.orders-list .item .name {
  margin-left: 65px;
}
.orders-list .item .name .info {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
.orders-list .item.active {
  background: blue;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-page">
  <div class="order-page-left">
    <div class="orders-list">
      <a href="#" class="item active">
        <div class="inner cfx">
          <div id="documentDetail0" class="detail">
            <span class="showDate">
              <span class="docDate" style="display: inline;">17.06
                                            </span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div id="documentName0" class="name">

            TEST1
            <div id="documentInfo0" class="info">

              TEST COMPANY - Branch I
              <br>52.50 € s87dff634769832
              <br>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-page-right color-box">
    <div class="order-page-content" style="display: block;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If user in any browser Zooms out red and blue elements separate from each other. I want to somehow prevent this from happening, but I don't know how, I am new in CSS and don't have experience. Here is also [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/099xad31/) link. If anyone can suggest something will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes have a fixed width, depending on what your goal really is you may want to use floats or a relative width like 25%,75%.

This worked for me, tested within FF 40, using the "Inspect Element" function.

```css
.order-page .order-page-right {
 //float right;
 width:100%;
}
```